# dynamic import webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Let say i have class bar.js

```
export default {
  sayBar(){
    alert('bar');
  },
}
```

now in index i want to lazy load on click
index.js

```
$('#test').on('click',(e)=>{
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "lazy-vendors/bar.js" */ './partials/bar').then( ({bar}) => {
        bar.default.sayBar()
    });
});
```

And compiling works fine but index.js is empty
part for webpack config

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import','@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
    }
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7","ie>=11"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

How can I enable promise and import() poliy ?